# Access variable through a protocol type in my case

Tags: swift

I have a protocol Foo:

```
protocol Foo {
   func doJob()
}
```

I have a class conform to the protocol but also have its own variable `name`:

```
class Bar : Foo {
  var name = ""

  // conform to protocol
  func doJob() {
    // implementations
  }
}
```

In my **extension** of `Foo`, I would like to check if `self` is an instance of `Bar`, if so, I want to update its `name` value. Here is what I tried:

```
extension Foo {
   func someJob() {
      if self is Bar {
          ((Bar) self).name = "John"
       }
   }
}
```

But seems Swift compiler doesn't allow that, compiler tells me "Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'" which doesn't make sense to me. How to achieve what I want to achieve?

Comment: how about `if let barSelf = self as? Bar { barself.name = "" }` or `extension Foo where Self == Bar { ... }`...?

Comment: You are using a C-Style cast. In Swift, use `(self as? Bar)?.name = "John"`

Comment: Why downvoting? Because it is too simple question? I tried googled & tried what is in my mind, then I asked here. But thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can cherrypick:

## option-1

make the protocol extension only for `Bar` instances who conforms `Foo`:

```
extension Foo where Self == Bar { // or Self: Bar it is up to what you want
    func someJob() {
        self.name = "..."
    }
}
```

---

## option-2

try to downcast `self` as `Bar` in the method's body:

```
extension Foo {
    func someJob() {
        if let barSelf = self as? Bar {
            barSelf.name = "..."
        }
    }
}
```